# How to Add ThemeRoller ui-lightness theme to my Datatable in rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my web application I have used datables to display data. I have used [This](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables)
gem to implement this and also followed [this episode form RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast). Now my table looks like exactly as shown in RailsCasts episode.

But I want to show it like [this](http://datatables.net/styling/themes/ui-lightness) one. But I searched in the internet but didn't get any material regarding this. So how can this be done?